# Determining Perfect Hash Lookup Table for Pearson Hash

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, pearson, perfect-hash

I'm developing a programming language, and in my programming language, I'm storing objects as hash tables.  The hash function I'm using is [Pearson Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing), which depends on a 256-bit lookup table.  Here's the function:

```
char* pearson(char* name, char* lookup)
{
    char index = '\0';
    while(*name)
    {
        index = lookup[index ^ *name];
        name++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

My question is, given a fixed group of fewer than 256 member names, how can one determine a `lookup` table such that `pearson()` will return unique characters within a contiguous range starting from `'\0'`.  In other words, I need an algorithm to create a lookup table for a [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).  This will allow me to have objects that take up no more space than the number of their members.  This will be done at compile time, so speed isn't a huge concern, but faster would be better.  It would be easy to brute force this, but I think (hope) there's a better way.

Here's an example: given member variables 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz' in a class, I want to determine a `lookup` such that:

```
pearson('foo',lookup) == (char) 0
pearson('bar',lookup) == (char) 1
pearson('baz',lookup) == (char) 2
```

Note that the order doesn't matter, so the following result would also be acceptable:

```
pearson('foo',lookup) == (char) 2
pearson('bar',lookup) == (char) 0
pearson('baz',lookup) == (char) 1
```

In an ideal world, all names that aren't in the table would return a value greater than 2 because this would allow me to avoid a check and possibly even avoid storing the member names, but I don't think this is possible, so I'll have to add an extra check to see if it's in the table.  Given this, it probably would save time to not initialize values in the lookup table which aren't used (collisions don't matter, because if it collides and fails the check, it isn't in the object at all, so the collision doesn't need to be resolved; only the error needs to be handled).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly doubt that you will be able to find a solution with brute force if the number of member names is too high. Thanks to the birthday paradox the probability that no collisions exist (i.e., two hashes are the same) is approximately 1:5000 for 64 and 1:850,000,000 for 96 member names. From the structure of your hash function (it's derived from a cryptographic construction that is designed to "mix" things well) I don't expect that an algorithms exists that solves your problem (but I would definitely be interested in such a beast).

Your ideal world is an illusion (as you expected): there are 256 characters you can append to 'foo', no two of them giving a new word with a same hash. As there are only 256 possibilities for the hash values, you can therefore append a character to 'foo' so that its hash is the same as any of the hashes of 'foo', 'bar' or 'baz'.

Why don't you use an existing library like [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: He does not want to use CMPH as the constant factors for CMPH are way too high, and a good pearson is much faster for <100.000 keys. The various CMPH variants only pay off >100.000 keys.
pearson is perfect for this usecase, even with accepting 1-3 collisions. But he doesn't even need collisions, he wants it as better bloom. 
Brute force search for pearson tables is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is an sorted and no-duplicated-element array that you can do binary search on. If the key is in the array, the index is the "hash". Otherwise, you get the size of the array. It is O(nlogn) compares to lookup table O(1), but it is good enough for small number of elements - 256 in your case.

Comment: The array doesn't need to be sorted, it's a hashmap using a perfect hash.  The idea is to have lookup time be constant (insertion and removal don't occur).